# Python regex pattern definition excluding a character

Tags: python, regex

I am writing a simple `Java` source file parser in `Python`.  The main objective is to extract a list of method declarations.  A method starts with `public|private|protected` (I assume there are no `friendly` methods without an access modifier, which is acceptable in my code base) and ends with a `{` but can't contain `;` (could be multiple lines).

So my current `regex` pattern looks like:

```
((public|private|protected).*\n*.*?({|;))
```

I am not sure how to say the entire match group can't contain `;` so I was trying to say get me something that ends with either `{` or `;`, whichever comes first, non-greedy.  However, that doesn't work and here is a chunk where it fails:

```
private static final AtomicInteger refCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

protected int getSomeVar() {
```

You can see that there is a variable declaration before the method declaration that starts with `private` but it does not have a `{`.  So this is returned as one match and I wanted to have it as two matches, then I would be discarding the variable declaration in separate non-regex logic.  But if you know how to exclude a `;` before `{`, that would work too.

Essentially, how do I tell in a Python regex expression that a certain character (or a sub pattern) must not occur within the main pattern?

Comment: The most easiest way that come into my mind is to have another regular expression to eliminate the one that contains those certain character(s), so if (re.match(".*;.*", your_stuff) == None): then you know the string doesn't contain any semicolon

Comment: i was hoping for something slightly more elegant

Comment: I don't see why you're complicating things, isn't [`(?s)(public|private|protected).*?[{;]`](http://regex101.com/r/cI0pY2) enough or am I missing something ?

Comment: i need \n for multi line declarations

Comment: @amphibient `(?s)` sets the `s` modifier to match newlines with `.` (dots). So `.*?` will match newlines if the `s` modifier is set.

Comment: you are right, @HamZa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finally worked:

```
((public|private|protected)[^;{]*?{)
```

Notice how I had to specify to exclude both `;` and `{` before the first {

Comment: If you aren't using dots `.` then setting `(?s)` would have no effect. [DOCS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negated character class to say "any character except (newline or) left brace or semicolon".

```
((public|private|protected)[^;{]*\n*[^;{]*?({|;))
```

Comment: i am having problems with that.  It does exclude the `;` sign but that was getting me everything up until the first ;, even multiple {s

Comment: Updated: I added the left brace to the exclude expression, too.